# colons equals operator in R? new syntax?

Tags: r, colon-equals

While reading http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html, I noticed the code has := sprinkled in it.  I assume that is a new way of providing arguments to a function?  What is it exactly?

```
mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, size := input_slider(10, 1000)) %>%
  layer_points(fill := "red") %>%
  layer_points(stroke := "black", fill := NA)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, `:=` is simply ggvis' syntax for assigning fixed values; in contrast, `=` would here be used to assign a variable value. As you might have noticed in your code example, on the right hand side, there are only such values as "red" or NA, therefore `:=` is the right operator to use in this context. If you would like "size" to depend on the "mpg" column, for example, you could write `size = mpg`, using the usual equals sign.

I admit that I am not familiar enough with `:=` to say whether there are other packages which have adopted this operator as well.

> From http://ggvis.rstudio.com/properties-scales.html (see for further examples and information):
>
> "The props() function uses the = operator for mapping (scaled), and the
>   := operator for setting (unscaled). It also uses the ~ operator to
>   indicate that an expression should be evaluated in the data (and in
>   ggvis, the data can change); without the ~ operator, the expression is
>   evaluated immediately in the current environment. Generally speaking,
>   you’ll want to use ~ for variables in the data, and not use it for
>   constant values."

Comment: Package data.table uses the `:=` syntax for assignment of values within a `j` statement. In the `data.table` context, this is to avoid creating copies of the entire object (as would happen with `<-` or `=`), which can be very slow for large objects.

Comment: I thought introduced operators had to be surrounded by %%

Comment: Is it possible to create my own := operator?

Comment: @Chris: yep, you just use `\`:=\` = function(x,y){...}` where `...` probably uses [Non-Standard Evaluation tricks](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) like `substitute()` and friends.  (better a little late than a little never)