# ":" operator in data table ( This is not regarding the := but only : can anyone please suggest.)

Tags: r, datatable

Using the  `":"` operator I'm trying to add columns in `j` argument in data table. These are simple 6 months  and 12 Months .. 36 months aggregations

```
OrderQty36M[,':='(Stat6M=sum(M14:M19)),(Stat12M=sum(M14:M25))]
```

Can the `":"` argument be used as a sequence operator in data table or there is some other way?

> in `[.data.table`(OrderQty36M, , `:=`(Stat6M = sum(M14:M19)), (Stat12M = sum(M14:M25))) :
>     The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (1). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (36703).
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In M14:M25 :
>     numerical expression has 36703 elements: only the first used
>   2: In M14:M25 :
>     numerical expression has 36703 elements: only the first used

Comment: Possible duplicate of 1. [When should I use the := operator in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029944/when-should-i-use-the-operator-in-data-table) 2. [What is the R assignment operator := for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817780/what-is-the-r-assignment-operator-for) 3. [colons equals operator in R? new syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077483/colons-equals-operator-in-r-new-syntax) 4. [Why is := allowed as an infix operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269423/why-is-allowed-as-an-infix-operator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use the := operator in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029944/when-should-i-use-the-operator-in-data-table)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things confused in how you are trying to use data.table here:

1. Your calculation for Stats12M is in the by column which I don't believe is intended. The brackets from the Stats6M calculation should be extended around the Stats12M calculation.
2. I don't think that data.table can select columns with the syntax M14:M19. Fortunately, dplyr can using the select function.
3. I think you are intending to sum across rows rather than the columns so you want to use rowSums rather than sum.

My corrected version of the code is below.

```
OrderQty36M[,':='(Stat6M=rowSums(select(.SD,M14:M19)), Stat12M=rowSums(select(.SD,M14:M25)))][]
```