# Difference between := and = operator in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'm super new to TradingView Pine Script and I didn't find a proper reference for understanding the difference between the `:=` and `=` operators.

Does anyone have a reference or description?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the := operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405820/what-is-the-operator)

Comment: Yes, that helped too, thanks for your note

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> = is used to declare and initialize variables := is used to assign values to variables after initialization, transforming them into
> mutable variables(any immutable variable).

follow [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-assignmenthttps://) to know more in details about :=