# How to address specific month&day in a Boolean variable?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

For testing a strategy on a forex currency pair, to avoid news-based spikes, I need to exclude specific time (read from the forex calendar). Address hours and minutes is okay for me but I couldn't manage to address for example 5 February (any year).

I have a suspicion that I should use `dayofmonth` but the following expression didn't exclude 5 February. I must have made an obvious error but couldn't use the manual successfully. (Double-checked: there's truly a `not(TimeToAvoid)` part in the proper IF block.)

```
TimeToAvoid = month == 2 and dayofmonth == 5
```

Comment: It should work actually. We are going to need more code and possibly a screenshot of what's happening.

Comment: I'll dig deeper then, thank you.

Comment: ‍♂️ That double check should have been triple… Only the Long half of Strategy Orders had the criteria of avoiding the time, the Short half didn't. ‍♂️ 

Answer (score 2):

Do note that the variables like `month` are tied to the UNIX time of the candle's open. For forex exchanges, Feb 5 candle opens on Feb 4, and Feb 6 candle opens on Feb 5, so the open on the Feb 5 daily candle returns `dayofmonth` of 4. As such, the expression you provided will be `true` for the end part of the Feb 5 candle and the beginning part of the Feb 6 candle. I can't guarantee that this is the source of your issue, but it might be.

To work around this, use `month(time_tradingday, "UTC+0")` and `dayofmonth(time_tradingday, "UTC+0")` -- the `time_tradingday` variable exists specifically to return the timestamp of the trading day the candle belongs to (00:00 UTC of said trading day, to be precise, which is why we additionally pass UTC+0 to the functions to make sure they parse the timestamp properly). Compare how these two approaches color bars on any forex symbol:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
TimeToAvoid = month == 2 and dayofmonth == 5
TradingDayToAvoid = month(time_tradingday, "UTC+0") == 2 and dayofmonth(time_tradingday, "UTC+0") == 5
bgcolor(TimeToAvoid ? color.new(color.red, 80) : na)
bgcolor(TradingDayToAvoid ? color.new(color.green, 80) : na)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know much of pinescript,
but wouldn't a `:=` be more appropriate in this context (and first define TimeToAvoid at the beginning of code with something like `var bool TimeToAvoid = false`)?

See also the answer in [Difference between := and = operator in pine script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759873/difference-between-and-operator-in-pine-script)

Comment: No but it's quite interesting, actually. When you need a lamp to light up then stay in its new state after the conditions are gone (and another condition should switch the lamp off sometimes later), then var bool & :=. 

But if you need that the Boolean variable be true ONLY WHEN the conditions are happening but not after, then it's just "Variable = condition". :)

Comment: A normal variable will be reset and recalculated on each and every candle. A `var` variable will just be created/declared but it won't be reset. Of course if you recalculate this variable on each candle unconditionally, then you just have a 'normal' variable. The power of the  `var` variable emerges when you modify them when some specific conditions apply.