# Why does weekofyear(time) start at a Tuesday rather than Monday?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In building the foundation for an indicator that Labels OPEX calibrated for the charts timeframe, I'm encountering unexpected results from weekofyear(time) returning Tuesday's rather than the expected Mondays for the start of a trading week. I have a list of various Option Products and the date and times of expiry.

My pseudocode is something like this:

1.Check chart timeframe

2.If monthly, then Label Quarterly OPEX products.

3.If weekly, then, in addition to above, Label Monthly OPEX products on that week.

4.If daily, then, in addition to above, Label Daily and Weekly OPEX products on that day of expiry.

5.If intraday, then, in addition to above, Label Times of OPEX products expiring at that time of day and day of week.

6.Check the current bar against the list of Option Products/Time of OPEX and Label that bar.

Building a way to check chart's timeframe started with the following code structure. I was expecting weekofyear(time) to return the start of the week as a Monday but an unexpected Tuesdays were returned.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Start of Month/Week Label', overlay=true)

// Check if the current bar is the first bar of the month
is_monthStart = month(time) != month(time[1])

// Plot a label at the start of each month
if is_monthStart
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, text="M: " + str.tostring(month(time)), style=label.style_label_down, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white)

if timeframe.isdwm
    if timeframe.isdaily    
// Check if the current bar is the first bar of the week
        is_weekStart    = weekofyear(time) != weekofyear(time[1])

// Plot a label at the start of each week
        if is_weekStart
            label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, yloc=yloc.belowbar, text="W: " + str.tostring(weekofyear(time)), style=label.style_label_up, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white)
```

[image]

Comment: Upon further research, I think it might have something to do with the chart Timezone offset from UTC.

Comment: Yes, time returns in the exchanges time zone. You will need to adjust to either match that or use a time zone to return the time in that zone

Comment: This issue is not really related to your chart's timezone. It is related to the openning time of the bar.

Answer (score 1):

This symbol is traded overnight, which means that a bar for the Nth trading day starts on day N-1 and ends on day N. The `time` variable returns the timestamp of the bar's open, so converting the `time` of the first bar of the month will return the day before it. You can work around it by replacing `time` with `time_close` or `time_tradingday`; see [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78061588/14296621) for some more info.

Additionally, if your goal is to check when a new month opens, you can use a more convenient `timeframe.change()` function, in your case it would be `timeframe.change("1M")` for new month and `timeframe.change("1W")` for new week.

Comment: Excellent suggestion and solved the problem with elegance, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Variables like `time`will use the UNIX time based on the time of the bar's open.

From the reference manual:

> Note that this variable returns the timestamp based on the time of the
> bar's open. Because of that, for overnight sessions (e.g. EURUSD,
> where Monday session starts on Sunday, 17:00) this variable can return
> time before the specified date of the trading day. For example, on
> EURUSD, dayofmonth(time) can be lower by 1 than the date of the
> trading day, because the bar for the current day actually opens one
> day prior.

This is what you are experiencing. In order to solve this issue, there is another built-in variable `time_tradingday` which you can use.

> **time_tradingday**
>
> The beginning time of the trading day the current bar belongs to, in
> UNIX format (the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since
> 00:00:00 UTC, 1 January 1970).
>
> **REMARKS** 
> The variable is useful for overnight sessions, where the current day's session can start on the previous calendar day (e.g., on
> EURUSD the Monday session will start on Sunday, 17:00). Unlike time,
> which would return the timestamp for Sunday at 17:00 for the Monday
> daily bar, time_tradingday will return the timestamp for Monday,
> 00:00.
>
> When used on timeframes higher than 1D, time_tradingday returns the
> trading day of the last day inside the bar (e.g. on 1W, it will return
> the last trading day of the week).

Below could should do it.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Start of Month/Week Label', overlay=true)

// Check if the current bar is the first bar of the month
is_monthStart = month(time) != month(time[1])

// Plot a label at the start of each month
if is_monthStart
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, text="M: " + str.tostring(month(time)), style=label.style_label_down, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white)

if timeframe.isdwm
    if timeframe.isdaily    
// Check if the current bar is the first bar of the week
        is_weekStart    = weekofyear(time_tradingday) != weekofyear(time_tradingday[1])

// Plot a label at the start of each week
        if is_weekStart
            label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, yloc=yloc.belowbar, text="W: " + str.tostring(weekofyear(time_tradingday)), style=label.style_label_up, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white)
```

[image]

Comment: There are some Months were the indicator aligns with the 1st day and other Months were is does not (11, 12, 2, 3)

The following code edit solved the problem of the offset; </br>
is_monthStart = timeframe.change('1M')