# Python script extracting specific lines from directory containing multiple text files

Tags: python, text

I'm fairly new to Python and have created this Python script via Chat GPT and looking at a few questions on this site. It works on the files I have, but it's very hard coded to these specific text files.  How can I make it less hard coded, so it searches and finds the lines needed?

Here is my code, and below a sample of the `.txt` files it's processing.

```
import os

def extract_lines(input_file, output_file):
    
    with open(input_file, 'r') as file: # Reads in las filename
        linea = [line for line in file if line.startswith('lasinfo')]
        linea = str(linea)
        linea = linea[31:-5]
        if len(linea) == 0:
            linea ='No filename defined!'
        
    with open(input_file, 'r') as file: # Reads in las datum
        lineb = [line for line in file if line.startswith('    PROJCS')]
        lineb = str(lineb)
        lineb = lineb[14:41]
        if len(lineb) == 0:
            lineb ='No DATUM defined!'

    with open(input_file, 'r') as file: # Reads in las point density details
        linec = [line for line in file if line.startswith('point density')]
        linec = str(linec)
        linec = linec[2:-4]
        lined = linec[27:31] # strips out density (points/m) value from statement
        if len(linec) == 0:
            linec ='No point density listed'
        
        lineout = linea + "," + lineb + "," + linec + "," + lined + '\n'

    with open(output_file, 'a') as output:
          output.write(lineout)
          
def process_txt_files(directory_path, output_file): # Scans directory for .txt files to process
    with open(output_file, 'w'):
        pass

    for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
            extract_lines(file_path, output_file)


directory_path = 'C:/Users/rinicholls/Richard/Gnarabup_LiDAR/LiDAR/Gnarabup_South_AVWS/reports'
output_file = 'density.txt'

process_txt_files(directory_path, output_file)
```

Text file:

```
lasinfo (231025) report for 'Gnarabup_South_sph_e310n6230_1AVWS.las'
reporting all LAS header entries:
  file signature:             'LASF'
  file source ID:             0
  global_encoding:            1
  project ID GUID data 1-4:   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  version major.minor:        1.4
  system identifier:          'LAStools (c) by rapidlasso GmbH'
  generating software:        'lasheight (210418) commercial'
  file creation day/year:     278/2023
  header size:                375
  offset to point data:       375
  number var. length records: 0
  point data format:          6
  point data record length:   30
  number of point records:    0
  number of points by return: 0 0 0 0 0
  scale factor x y z:         0.01 0.01 0.01
  offset x y z:               0 0 0
  min x y z:                  311439.81 6230000.08 -38.91
  max x y z:                  311999.99 6231999.80 -33.17
  start of waveform data packet record: 0
  start of first extended variable length record: 0
  number of extended_variable length records: 0
  extended number of point records: 7586
  extended number of points by return: 7586 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ...
  X            31143981   31199999
  Y           623000008  623199980
  Z               -3891      -3317
  intensity           0          0
  return_number       1          1
  number_of_returns   1          1
  edge_of_flight_line 0          1
  scan_direction_flag 0          1
  classification     13         13
  scan_angle_rank   -11         18
  user_data           1          1
  point_source_ID   174        177
  gps_time 363998052.416096 363998902.558917
  extended_return_number          1      1
  extended_number_of_returns      1      1
  extended_classification        13     13
  extended_scan_angle         -1820   2924
  extended_scanner_channel        0      0
number of first returns:        7586
number of intermediate returns: 0
number of last returns:         7586
number of single returns:       7586
covered area in square units/kilounits: 30136/0.03
point density: all returns 0.25 last only 0.25 (per square units)
      spacing: all returns 1.99 last only 1.99 (in units)
overview over extended number of returns of given pulse: 7586 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
histogram of classification of points:
            7586  wire guard (13)
```

Comment: Please be more clear about what hard coding you are talking about that you want to remove.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by hard-coded. If you want it to process all files, not just text files, remove the `if` statement. 
`if filename.endswith(".txt"):`

Comment: Sorry, by hard coding I mean I have used "linea = str(linea) and linea = linea[31:-5]" to put out the bits of the text file instead of some other way to find the bit of text I need.  So if a .txt file arrives with the wording spaced differently, the code won't work.

Comment: The code is, quite frankly, ridiculous. If you're just learning Python stay well away from ChatGPT - it will only confuse you and lead you down dubious pathways. Start [here](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

Comment: Fair enough, but at least the code works on my specific problem.  Learnt a lot today, hopefully my code improves from here ... and I'll stay away from GPT :)

Answer (score 1):

Without more examples, we have no idea how to generalize this. But reading the same file multiple times is obviously wasteful and slow; just read it into memory once and process the resulting list repeatedly if you have to. Better yet, process it once and extract the parts you want as you go.

(Notice also the somewhat more descriptive variable names. If there are many fields you want to extract, maybe put them all in a `dict`, or, down the line once you learn more, create a `class` which knows how to cope with various attributes.)

```
# prefer pathlib over os.*
from pathlib import Path

def extract_lines(input_file, output_handle):
    lasinfo = 'No filename defined!'
    projcs = 'No DATUM defined!'
    pdens = 'No point density listed'
    pdensnum = ''

    with open(input_file, 'r') as lines:
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith('lasinfo'):
                lasinfo = line[29:-2]
            elif line.startswith('    PROJCS'):
                projcs = line[11:39]
            elif line.startswith('point density'):
                pdens = line[:-1]
                pdensnum = pdens[27:31]

    lineout = ",".join([lasinfo, projcs, pdens, pdensnum]) + "\n"
    output_handle.write(lineout)
          
def process_txt_files(directory_path, output_file):
    dirpath = Path(directory_path)
    with open(output_file, 'w') as output_handle:
        for filepath in dirpath.iterdir():
            if filepath.suffix == ".txt":
                extract_lines(filepath, output_handle)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory_path = 'C:/Users/rinicholls/Richard/Gnarabup_LiDAR/LiDAR/Gnarabup_South_AVWS/reports'
    output_file = 'density.txt'
    process_txt_files(directory_path, output_file)
```

The offsets had to be updated because the ChatGPT code was weirdly collecting lines into an array and then converting it back to a single string, which would add junk formatting. But anyway, it's probably better to split the line into tokens and extract the one with numbers in it, or use a regular expression to target exactly the part you want:

```
import re
...
    elif m := re.match(r'^point density: all returns ([\d.]+)', line):
        pdens = line[2:-4]
        pdensnum =  float(m.group(1))
```

(then if you really have a `float`, you have to convert it back to `str` for the `join`). There seems to be a similar index error for the file name part.

As a general observation, defaulting to empty strings or a simple general sentinel value like `"N/A"` for when some piece of information could not be found would be helpful for downstream processing of the extracted data. It's unfortunate that the files you process are not properly machine-readable; try to fix that, and only use "human friendly" formatting for display, not when storing data in files.

You might also want to `raise` an exception if something crucial could not be found, like in this case I'm guessing the input file name from the `lasinfo` line. A traceback might seem a bit scary before you get used to them, but in fact it's better to be alerted immediately when something goes wrong, rather than have your script write reams of useless data as if nothing was wrong.

Tangentially, perhaps notice also the [walrus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405820/what-is-the-operator) in the regex example. In many languages, you would be able to say

```
    elif m = re.match(...):
        ... # do something with m
```

but Python generally abhors this use of "side effects". The statement `m = re.match(...)` returns `None` so you cannot use that as an expression for `elif`; Python 3.8 introduced this `:=` operator to allow you to explicitly assign and compare at the same time, but this was always somewhat controversial. However, this is precisely the sort of corner case where it's handy.

Comment: Tried running this but I get the error ... ImportError: No module named pathlib.

Comment: Are you on a _really_ old Python version? [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) was introduced in Python 3.4, released in 2016 and end-of-lifed in 2018.

Comment: Yes, looks like I have v2.7.18 .. came with the ArcGIS software I use.  I've only just started playing with python, I'm by no means a coder, so it's all trial an error.

Comment: If you are only just learning, you should probably ignore Python 2 and focus on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3. Python 2 was finally end-of-lifed in 2020 after a very long transition period. Maybe check if you have a command `python3` installed already. It would not be too hard to port this to Python 2 but it would probably be a disservice to you in the longer run.

Comment: Done, just downloaded and installed v3.12.1.  That 'pathlib' is now working.  I had to re-do all the line[x:x] numbers, they're now all off by 1 or 2.  Must be the way v2 to v3 reads?

Comment: No, string indexing has not changed between versions. But the weird `str(linea)` would convert a list of strings to a single string, which would add `['` at the beginning and `']` at the end, which I failed to account for when ditching that weirdness. Thanks for noticing; I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  At the very least I now have a current python version :)  That re:match line work, no idea what it's actually doing but will research some more.  My learning continues.

Comment: Understanding the basics of regular expressions is a matter of minutes. Like it says on the Othello game box: "It takes a minute to learn ... but a lifetime to master."